# Android resources.getColor() freezes code

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add views to `LinearLayout` dynamically on POST request finished inside a `fragment`.

Here is my function that creates and setups the view and returns it, then I add it to the `chatsRoot` via `addView()` method. No exceptions, but views are not added.

After some debug I noticed, that in logcat there is only one message "Banner created1" and no message "Banner created2", like if the program freezed on loading the color resource.

```kotlin
Log.d("VIEW", "Banner created1") // appears in logcat
val colorFrom = resources.getColor(R.color.banner_regular, null)
Log.d("VIEW", "Banner created2") // not appears in logcat
```

```kotlin
private fun generateBanner(chatData: ChatData):View? {
    val banner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_banner, null, false)

    banner.run {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.user_name).text = chatData.name
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.short_code).text = chatData.shortCode
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.short_message).text =
            chatData.lastMessage.let { it.substring(0, min(40, it.length)) + "..." }
        findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.unread_dot).visibility =
            if (chatData.hasUnread) VISIBLE else GONE
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date_time_text).text = chatData.lastMessageTime
    }

    Log.d("VIEW", "Banner created1")

    val colorFrom = resources.getColor(R.color.banner_regular, null)

    Log.d("VIEW", "Banner created2")

    val colorTo = resources.getColor(R.color.banner_clicked, null)

    val animation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(
        ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo, colorFrom
    ).apply {
        addUpdateListener {
            banner.setBackgroundColor(animatedValue as Int)
        }
    }

    banner.setOnClickListener {
        animation.start()
        openChat(chatData.uid)
    }

    return banner
}
```

`generateBanner()` is called here, same situation: top is printed, bottom is not

```
private fun addChatsToRoot(chats:List<ChatData>) {
    Log.d("VIEW", "Adding chats to root") // printed to logcat
    for(chatData in chats) {
        chatsData += chatData.uid to chatData

        val banner = generateBanner(chatData)
        chatsRoot.addView(banner)
    }
    Log.d("VIEW", "Chats are added to the layout") // not in logcat
}
```

I tried removing null parameter for the theme, nothing changed.
I also changed `resources` call to raw number representing white colors, layout created, nothing freezed the code, but layout inflated wrongly, `banner.height` is always zero, even if in its drawable file I set `minHeight`.

So it looks like I just cant load any kind of a resource from this fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,R.color.banner_regular)
```

Comment: applicationContext is not defined, so I required context, but code freezes the same, as it was: val colorFrom = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.banner_regular)

Comment: May be command the animation and try to run. You're using loop so need to verify with your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out all the problems were because I had a fragment inside another fragment. This caused problems not only with resource access, but also with inflating additional layout views.

My solution is to move fragments to one level and navigate using one navController